# Override default property with another property file at runtime

Tags: java, spring, properties

Lets say I have the following property files:

service.properties
service1.properties
service2.properties

My application would be making a bunch of service calls and will be using the default property file (service.properties). However, I would like to override it with service1.properties when service1 is making the call. Similarly service2.properties should override for service2 call.

For the rest of the service calls I would still like to use service.properties.

Any pointers as to how I should go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="service" class="com.concept.testing.Service">
<property name="url" value="${url.property}" />
<property name="user" value="${user.property}" />
<property name="password" value="password" />
<property name="app" value="Application" />
</bean>
```

Your scenario make sense to me only above scenario, where you want to say use a method 
of class Service whose few properties are constant and few need to be injected dynamically
from a property file. Since the class is same for all the service calls so you do not want to
define the different properties and beans for service1 and service2.

So here you can use the configuration inheritance in spring which can be defined like below :

```
<bean id="service1" parent="service">
<property name="url" value="${url1.property}" />
<property name="user" value="${user1.property}" />
</bean>

<bean id="service2" parent="service">
<property name="url" value="${url2.property}" />
<property name="user" value="${user2.property}" />
</bean>
```

So now you can inject the service1 bean for service1 call and service2 bean 
for service2 call. Their parent class is same but the only difference is in their 
configuration (i.e. url and name).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Amit. But as you see I have multiple override property files (service1.properties, service2.properties ..). Only in the scenario, when I'm making service1 call, I would like to override with service1.properties.

Comment: Why exactly you need the properties to be overriden at the runtime ? Is it like you want to reuse the bean defined in xml and just want to configure it during runtime ?

Comment: I want it to be at runtime, as based on the application logic I could make either service1 call or service2 call or both. Depending on the service call made, I want to provide the override file.

Comment: Check my answer, hope that will give you an idea. The values from property files are injected only during initializing the spring context, once that is done. You cannot reload the same values again.